# Asp.net mvc Razor fill values to textarea from text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to read a text file and fill those values in a text area. What is my mistake here

```
 @{
        var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/Files/myFile.txt");
        var ListFromFile= File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);
        @Html.TextArea("name", "", ListFromFile)
    }
    <textarea>
        @ListFromFile.ToList();
    </textarea>
```

Comment: What error you've received ?

Comment: It is not adding values to text area and it shows in second text area
        System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly set list as textarea value.So, you need to build a `string`.

You have to use the `StringBuilder` class for concatenating many strings together in a loop.

Please try this:

```
@{
    var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/Files/myFile.txt");
    var ListFromFile= File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string line in ListFromFile)
    {
       sb.Append(line + "\n");   
    }
    var str = new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

Then set textarea value:

```
<textarea>@Html.Raw(str)</textarea>
```

Or simply:

```
<textarea>@str</textarea>
```

**Another method is to use [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
@{
    var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/Files/myFile.txt");
    var ListFromFile= File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);
    var str = String.Join("\n", ListFromFile.ToArray());
}
<textarea>@str</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be what you are looking for:

```
@{
  var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/Files/myFile.txt");
  var ListFromFile = File.ReadAllText(dataFile);

}
@Html.TextArea("name", ListFromFile, new { cols=40, rows=5})
```

it would seem you are creating the TextArea twice in your original code and in the Razor element you have the args specified in the wrong order. I also changed the File method being used so that only the string contents are being returned instead of a list.